# when I use the LXC IP on the browser it gives "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc, lxd

**Basically I want to establish website with the LXC.**
so I installed LXD and created LXC called app1, then installed apache2. All are running, but when I use the LXC IP on the browser it gives "This site can’t be reached", I disabled the ufw even though I removed it but nothing happen.

Here are the commands that I did with their results:

```
$ sudo lxc list
| app1 | RUNNING | 10.221.72.14 (eth0) | fd42:969c:2638:6357:216:3eff:fe59:efd7 (eth0) | CONTAINER | 0

$ sudo lxc network ls
| br0    | bridge   | NO      |             | 0       |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
| ens3   | physical | NO      |             | 0       |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
| lxdbr0 | bridge   | YES     |             | 2       |
+--------+----------+---------+-------------+---------+
| virbr0 | bridge   | NO      |             | 0       |

$ sudo lxc network show lxdbr0
config:
  ipv4.address: 10.221.72.1/24
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv6.address: fd42:969c:2638:6357::1/64
  ipv6.nat: "true"
description: ""
name: lxdbr0
type: bridge
used_by:
- /1.0/instances/app1
- /1.0/profiles/default
managed: true
status: Created
locations:
- none
```

Comment: Did you able to solve this problem?

Comment: actually no, I could not solve this issue that time.